# Vue как виджет на сторонний сайт

Tags: vue.js, vue3

**Задача:** Создать виджет на vue, который можно подключать на сторонниках сайтах.
Пример:

```
<my-widget />
<script src='random url to widget'></script>
```

**Что получилось сделать:**
Билд приложения, папка dist - 1 js файл.
Подключаю на другом сайте через скрипт + `<div id='my-widget'></div>`

На странице появляется, но нет стилей. (Если важно, то стили прописаны на scss). Vue3/webpack.
Что делаю не так? Либо, может быть, есть более лаконичное решение? - ранее не сталкивался с данным кейсом.